# APEX Trigger wont save - Error Message

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-trigger

i have this APEX trigger and I'm getting this error but not sure why "Error: Compile Error: expecting a left angle bracket, found 'oppcntctrle' at line 13 column 10"

```
trigger updatecontactrolecount on Opportunity (before insert, before update)
{

Boolean isPrimary;
Integer iCount;
Map<String, Opportunity> oppty_con = new Map<String, Opportunity>();//check        if the contact role is needed and add it to the oppty_con map
for (Integer i = 0; i < Trigger.new.size(); i++) 
{
oppty_con.put(Trigger.new[i].id,
Trigger.new[i]); 
}
isPrimary = False; 
for (List oppcntctrle :[select OpportunityId from OpportunityContactRole where (OpportunityContactRole.IsPrimary = True and  OpportunityContactRole.OpportunityId in :oppty_con.keySet())])
{
if (oppcntctrle .Size() >0)
{
isPrimary = True; 
}
}
iCount = 0;
for (List oppcntctrle2 : [select OpportunityId from OpportunityContactRole where (OpportunityContactRole.OpportunityId in :oppty_con.keySet())])//Query for Contact Roles

{ 
if (oppcntctrle2 .Size()>0) 
{
iCount= oppcntctrle2 .Size(); 
}
}
for (Opportunity Oppty : system.trigger.new) //Check if roles exist in the map or contact role isn't required 
{
Oppty.Number_of_Contacts_Roles_Assigned__c = iCount;
Oppty.Primary_Contact_Assigned__c =isPrimary; 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
for (List oppcntctrle :[select OpportunityId from OpportunityContactRole where (OpportunityContactRole.IsPrimary = True and  OpportunityContactRole.OpportunityId in :oppty_con.keySet())])
```

should be

```
List<OpportunityContactRole> oppcntctrle = [select OpportunityId from OpportunityContactRole where (OpportunityContactRole.IsPrimary = True and  OpportunityContactRole.OpportunityId in :oppty_con.keySet())];
```

The same for

```
for (List oppcntctrle2 : [select OpportunityId from OpportunityContactRole where (OpportunityContactRole.OpportunityId in :oppty_con.keySet())])//Query for Contact Roles
```

should be changed to

```
List<OpportunityContactRole> oppcntctrle2 = [select OpportunityId from OpportunityContactRole where (OpportunityContactRole.OpportunityId in :oppty_con.keySet())];//Query for Contact Roles
```